# having asked vs have asked

Tags: grammar

> SQUIRE TRELAWNEY, Dr Liversy, and the rest of these gentlemen having
>   asked me to write down the whole particulars about Treasure Island,
>   from the begining to the end, keeping nothing back but the bearings of
>   the island, and that only because there is still treasure not yet
>   lifed.

Where is the predicate, why use `having` instead of `have` in the above paragraph?

Thanks.

Comment: Please leave a comment with your down vote, so I can ask a more valuable question next time.

Comment: It was my downvote, for the reason given in the first sentence of @Peter's answer. Your text as cited isn't a complete sentence, since it lacks the main subject + verb ***I take up my pen***. For any future questions like this, please ensure you *fully and accurately* cite the text causing you a problem. Also include a link to the original, in case there's additional relevant context before or after the cited text. Finally, please consider using [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) if *as a non-native speaker* you're having problems parsing "presumed valid" text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi, I am not a native english speaker and not fully understand the sentence. I even do not know whether I have cited the right fully text. So thanks for the ell advice.

Comment: @towry: the sentence ends when you get to a period (but not usually one signaling an abbreviation, like Mr.) Back when Robert Louis Stevenson was writing, people generally used longer sentences than they do today. Some long sentences can be incredibly confusing, even for native English speakers; however, this one is fairly clear.

Comment: @Peter: It's "quite clear" to native speakers, *provided* they're looking at the full text. I assume that - like me - as soon as you realise you're looking at an ***X [verbing] Y*** construction in the initial position, you're *intensely* preoccupied with remembering that you need to identify the expected comma at end of that clause, after which you expect to find a clause with the primary subject+verb. This might well be difficult for non-native speakers when there are multiple "sub-clauses" with commas ("false alarms" that *don't* reflect the expected end), which is why I suggested ELL here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The predicate is not there because you didn't quote the entire sentence in your question. The main clause of the sentence is the one starting *I take up my pen ...*

> Squire Trelawney, Dr. Livesey, and the rest of these gentlemen having asked me to write down the whole particulars about Treasure Island, from the beginning to the end, keeping nothing back but the bearings of the island, and that only because there is still treasure not yet lifted, I take up my pen in the year of grace 17-, and go back to the time when my father kept the "Admiral Benbow" inn, and the brown old seaman, with the sabre cut, first took up his lodging under our roof.